# Java. GUI WindowBuilder read from JTextField by clicking button

Tags: java, swing, search, actionlistener, jtextfield

I'm useing WindowBuilder, and I want to ask how to search in a text file for specific word, which I enter to `JTextField` by clicking a <kbd>Search</kbd> button? My program looks like this:

[image http://img252.imageshack.us/img252/1410/39931036.png](http://img252.imageshack.us/img252/1410/39931036.png)

This is my `JTextField` and `JButton`:

```
private void initialize() {
    frmInformacijaApieMuzikos = new JFrame();
    frmInformacijaApieMuzikos.setResizable(false);
    frmInformacijaApieMuzikos.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
        .getImage(KDVizualizuotas.class.getResource(
        "/lt/kvk/i3_2/kalasnikovas_stanislovas/resources/Sidebar-Music-Blue-icon.png")));
    frmInformacijaApieMuzikos.setTitle("Muzikos stiliai");
    frmInformacijaApieMuzikos.setBounds(100, 100, 262, 368);
    frmInformacijaApieMuzikos.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    txtStilius = new JTextField();
    txtStilius.setBounds(10, 34, 128, 20);
    txtStilius.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnIekoti = new JButton("Ie\u0161koti");
    btnIekoti.setBounds(146, 36, 89, 19);
    btnIekoti.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });
}
```

I have code "search in text file" which works in console, but I need to remake it: "Enter word to `JTextField` (not in console) and click search button (not Enter button) to find It". I don't know how to make It.

My code (These last 2 codes you can skip):

```
package lt.kvk.i3_2.kalasnikovas_stanislovas;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Stilius {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {


            FileReader fr = new FileReader("src/lt/kvk/i3_2/kalasnikovas_stanislovas/Stiliai.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String stiliuSarasas;
            while((stiliuSarasas = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(stiliuSarasas);
                }
            fr.close();


          /** String help = "";  
            System.out.println("Iveskite stiliaus pavadinima apie kuri ieskote informacijos (daugiau funkciju - Pagalba)");

            if ("Pagalba".equalsIgnoreCase(help)) { 
                help = input.nextLine();
            Pagalba pagalba = new Pagalba(help);
            }**/


            String kitasStilius = "Taip";       

            while (!"Ne".equalsIgnoreCase(kitasStilius)) {   
                if ("Taip".equalsIgnoreCase(kitasStilius)) {                 
                    System.out.println("Iveskite stiliaus pavadinima apie kuri ieskote informacijos");

                    String stilius = input.nextLine();
                    Veiksmai stiliausPaieska = new Veiksmai(stilius);   

                }
                else if ("Ne".equalsIgnoreCase(kitasStilius)) {

                } 
                else{
                     System.out.println("Neteisingai pasirinkta.");
                }
                System.out.println("Ar norite ieskoti kito stiliaus?");
                System.out.println("Iveskite: Taip or Ne");
                kitasStilius = input.nextLine();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e.toString());
        }
     }
}
```

and other class

```
package lt.kvk.i3_2.kalasnikovas_stanislovas;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Veiksmai {

        public Veiksmai(String stilius) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/lt/kvk/i3_2/kalasnikovas_stanislovas/Miestai.txt"));
        int counter = 0;                
        String line;

        System.out.println("Ieskoma informacija apie " + stilius);
        ArrayList<String> miestuSarasas = new ArrayList<String>();

        String miestas = null;
        while (( line = bf.readLine()) != null){
            if (line.trim().length() == 0) miestas = null;
               else if (miestas == null) miestas = line;
               int indexfound = line.indexOf(stilius);
               if (indexfound > -1) {
                counter++;
                miestuSarasas.add(miestas);
               }                   
        }
        if (counter > 0) {
            System.out.println(stilius + " turi " + counter + " remejus: " + miestuSarasas);  

            try {
                 File file = new File("src/lt/kvk/i3_2/kalasnikovas_stanislovas/Atsakymas.txt");

                    if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write(stilius + " turi " + counter + " remejus: " + miestuSarasas+"\n");
                bw.close();
    } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Klaida, nerastas muzikos stilius");
        }
        bf.close();
    }
    public void stabdyti(){

    }
    public void sarasas() throws IOException{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("src/lt/kvk/i3_2/kalasnikovas_stanislovas/Stiliai.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String stiliuSarasas;
        while((stiliuSarasas = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(stiliuSarasas);
            }
        fr.close();
    }

}
```

Could you help me, please? I'm still newbie in Java. I tried so many, but everything wont work.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: These last 2 codes of my code you can skip. I need only idea / help / examples how to search in text file specific word, which I enter to JTextField by clicking "Search" button?
As I said I have my code which works in console I only need to know how to visualize It.

Comment: *"These last 2 codes of my code you can skip."*  Oh, thank you.  But I choose to skip anything besides an SSCCE.

Comment: Create a search class that has a method (called find for example), pass the file to be searched and the text to search for to it. Use JTextField#getText to retrieve the value from the text field and a JFileChooser to select the (if required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this program long time back, it highlights the word in `JTextField` automatically.Hope this helps:

[image]

Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.*;


public class Stringtext extends JFrame
                       implements DocumentListener {

private JTextField entry;
private JLabel jLabel1;
private JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private JLabel status;
private JTextArea textArea;

final static Color  HILIT_COLOR = Color.YELLOW;
final static Color  ERROR_COLOR = Color.PINK;
final static String CANCEL_ACTION = "cancel-search";

final Color entryBg;
final Highlighter hilit;
final Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter;


public Stringtext() {
    initComponents();
  /*code to put text from a file
    InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("file2.txt");
    try {
        textArea.read(new InputStreamReader(in), null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  */
    textArea.setText("hello Mr! please try to post an SSCCE next time otherwise don't you DARE to...");
    hilit = new DefaultHighlighter();
    painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(HILIT_COLOR);
    textArea.setHighlighter(hilit);

    entryBg = entry.getBackground();
    entry.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);

    InputMap im = entry.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
    ActionMap am = entry.getActionMap();
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ESCAPE"), CANCEL_ACTION);
    am.put(CANCEL_ACTION, new CancelAction()); 

    }


  private void initComponents() {
    entry = new JTextField();
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    status = new JLabel();
    jLabel1 = new JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("TextFieldDemo");

    textArea.setColumns(20);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setRows(5);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setEditable(true);
    jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(textArea);

    jLabel1.setText("Enter text to search:");

    GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);

ParallelGroup hGroup = layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING);
SequentialGroup h1 = layout.createSequentialGroup();
ParallelGroup h2 = layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER);

h1.addContainerGap();

h2.addComponent(jScrollPane1, GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 450, Short.MAX_VALUE);
h2.addComponent(status, GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 450, Short.MAX_VALUE);

SequentialGroup h3 = layout.createSequentialGroup();
h3.addComponent(jLabel1);
h3.addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED);
h3.addComponent(entry, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 321, Short.MAX_VALUE);

h2.addGroup(h3);

h1.addGroup(h2);

h1.addContainerGap();

hGroup.addGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, h1);

layout.setHorizontalGroup(hGroup);



ParallelGroup vGroup = layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING);

SequentialGroup v1 = layout.createSequentialGroup();

v1.addContainerGap();

ParallelGroup v2 = layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE);
v2.addComponent(jLabel1);
v2.addComponent(entry, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE);

v1.addGroup(v2);
v1.addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED);
v1.addComponent(jScrollPane1, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 233, Short.MAX_VALUE);
v1.addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED);
v1.addComponent(status);
v1.addContainerGap();

//Add the group v1 to the group vGroup
vGroup.addGroup(v1);
//Create the vertical group
layout.setVerticalGroup(vGroup);
pack();
   }

   public void search() {
    hilit.removeAllHighlights();

    String s = entry.getText();

    if (s.length() <= 0) {
        message("Nothing to search");
        return;
      }

    String content = textArea.getText();

    int index = content.indexOf(s, 0);
    if (index >= 0) {   // match found
        try {
            int end = index + s.length();
            hilit.addHighlight(index, end, painter);
            textArea.setCaretPosition(end);
            entry.setBackground(entryBg);
            message("'" + s + "' found. Press ESC to end search");
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        entry.setBackground(ERROR_COLOR);
        message("'" + s + "' not found. Press ESC to start a new search");
    }
   }

  void message(String msg) {
    status.setText(msg);
   }

   public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
    search();
   }

  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
    search();
   }

   public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
   }

  class CancelAction extends AbstractAction {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        hilit.removeAllHighlights();

        entry.setText("boo");
        entry.setBackground(entryBg);
    }
   }


   public static void main(String args[]) {

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
    new Stringtext().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
   }
  }
```